# Differences between these three ways of defining a function in Scala

Tags: scala

Given three ways of expressing the same function `f(a) := a + 1`:

```
val f1 = (a:Int) => a + 1
def f2 = (a:Int) => a + 1
def f3:(Int => Int) = a => a + 1
```

How do these definitions differ?  The REPL does not indicate any obvious differences:

```
scala> f1
res38: (Int) => Int = <function1>
scala> f2
res39: (Int) => Int = <function1>
scala> f3
res40: (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: You should note that in the 2nd block above, evaluating `f1` in the REPL shows the value statically bound to `f1` while evaluating `f2` and `f3` show the result of *invoking* those methods. In particular, a new `Function1[Int, Int]` instance is produced every time either `f2` or `f3` is invoked, while `f1` is the same `Function1[Int, Int]` forever.

Comment: @RandallSchulz given that the val version does not require a new function instance, why would one ever use def in this case?

Comment: @virtualeyes The only situation that I can recall where one sees defs yielding FunctionN[...] values is in the combinator parser library. It's not very common to write methods that yield functions and virtually never would one use a def to yield many copies of a semantically / functionally unchanging function.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`f1` is a function that takes an integer and returns an integer.

`f2` is a method with zero arity that returns a function that takes an integer and returns an integer. (When you type `f2` at REPL later, it becomes a call to the method `f2`.)

`f3` is same as `f2`. You're just not employing type inference there.

Comment: Why `f1` is a `function` and `f2` is a `method`?

Comment: @Freewind, a function is an object with a method named `apply`. A method, well, is a method.

Comment: Awesome answer. Question: you say f2 has zero arity, but isn't it unary? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity "A nullary function takes no arguments. A unary function takes one argument." Just curious!

Comment: @MatthewCornell, `f2` itself accepts no arguments. The function object that it returns does.

Answer (score 122):

Inside a class, `val` is evaluated on initialization while `def` is evaluated only when, *and every time*, the function is called. In the code below you will see that x is evaluated the first time the object is used, but not again when the x member is accessed. In contrast, y is not evaluated when the object is instantiated, but is evaluated every time the member is accessed.

```
  class A(a: Int) {
    val x = { println("x is set to something"); a }
    def y = { println("y is set to something"); a }
  }

  // Prints: x is set to something
  val a = new A(1)

  // Prints: "1"
  println(a.x)

  // Prints: "1"                               
  println(a.x)

  // Prints: "y is set to something" and "1"                                  
  println(a.y)

  // Prints: "y is set to something" and "1"                                                                                   
  println(a.y)
```

Comment: @JacobusR is this true only inside a class?

Comment: for example:  scala> var b = 5
b: Int = 5

scala> val a: (Int => Int) = x => x + b
a: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> a(5)
res48: Int = 10

scala> b = 6
b: Int = 6

scala> a(5)
res49: Int = 11
I was expecting a(5) to return 10 and the value of b to have been inlined

Comment: @AndrewCassidy the function `a` is immutable and evaluated at initialisation, but `b` remains a mutable value. So the reference to `b` is set during initialisation, but the value stored by `b` remains mutable. For fun you could now create a new `val b = 123`. After this your `a(5)` will always give 11, since the `b` is now a completely new value.

Comment: @JacobusR thanks... this makes sense. This coincides with the definition of "lexical scope" since the function a carries a reference to original "var b". I guess what made me confused is that say: var b = 5; val c = b; b = 6; acts differently. I guess I shouldn't expect a function definition which carries around references to the original "lexical" scope to behave the same way as an Int.

Answer (score 3):

Executing a definition such as ***def*** x = e will not evaluate the expression *e*. Instead *e* is evaluated whenever *x* is used. Alternatively, Scala offers a value definition
***val*** x = e, which does evaluate the right-hand-side *e* as part of the evaluation
of the definition. If *x* is then used subsequently, it is immediately replaced by the
pre-computed value of *e*, so that the expression need not be evaluated again.

> Scala By Example
>   by **Martin Odersky**