# What is the difference between the following ways to write a function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, and have seen many ways to define a function but could not find a clear explanation on the differences, and when to use which form.

What are the main differences between the following function definitions?

1. With '='

   ```
   def func1(node: scala.xml.Node) = {
       print(node.label + " = " + node.text + ",")
   }
   ```
2. Without '='

   ```
   def func2 (node: scala.xml.Node) {
       print(node.label + " = " + node.text + ",")
   }
   ```
3. With '=>'

   ```
   def func3 = (node: scala.xml.Node) => {
       print(node.label + " = " + node.text + ",")
   }
   ```
4. As a var

   ```
   var func4 = (node: scala.xml.Node) => {
       print(node.label + " = " + node.text + ",")
   }
   ```
5. Without a block

   ```
   def func5 (node: scala.xml.Node) = print(node.label + " = " + node.text + ",")
   ```

They all seem to compile and render the same result when used as a callback for

```
    xmlNodes.iterator.foreach(...)
```

- Is there any difference in the bytecode each generate?
- Are there any guidlines when to use which form?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each of these questions has been answered elsewhere on this site, but I don't think anything handles them all together.  So:

#### Braces and equals

Methods defined with an equals sign return a value (whatever the last thing evaluates to).  Methods defined with only braces return `Unit`.  If you use an equals but the last thing evalutes to `Unit`, there is no difference.  If it's a single statement after an equals sign, braces are not required; this makes no difference to bytecode.  So 1., 2., and 5. are all essentially identical:

```
def f1(s: String) = { println(s) }     // println returns `Unit`
def f2(s: String) { println(s) }       // `Unit` return again
def f5(s: String) = println(s)         // Don't need braces; there's only one statement
```

#### Functions vs. methods

A function, often written `A => B`, is a subclass of one of the `Function` classes, e.g. `Function1[A,B]`.  Because this class has an `apply` method, which Scala magically calls when you just use parens without a method name, it looks like a method call--and it is, except it's a call on that `Function` object!  So if you write

```
def f3 = (s: String) => println(s)
```

then what you are saying is "`f3` should create an instance of `Function1[String,Unit]` which has an `apply` method that looks like `def apply(s: String) = println(s)`".  So if you say `f3("Hi")`, this is first calls `f3` to create the function object, and then calls the `apply` method.

It's rather wasteful to create the function object every single time you want to use it, so it makes more sense to store the function object in a var:

```
val f4 = (s: String) => println(s)
```

This holds one instance of the same function object that the `def` (method) would return, so you don't have to recreate it each time.

#### When to use what

People differ on the convention of `: Unit = ...` and `{ }`.  Personally, I write all methods that return `Unit` without an equals sign--this is an indication to me that the method is almost surely useless unless it has some sort of side-effect (mutates a variable, performs IO, etc.).  Also, I generally only use braces when required either because there are multiple statements or because the single statement is so complex I want a visual aid to tell me where it ends.

Methods should be used whenever you want, well, a method.  Function objects should be created any time you want to pass them into some other method to use them (or should be specified as parameters any time you want to be able to apply a function).  For example, suppose you want to be able to scale a value:

```
class Scalable(d: Double) {
  def scale(/* What goes here? */) = ...
}
```

You could supply a constant multiplier.  Or you could supply something to add and something to multiply.  But most flexibly, you'd just ask for an arbitrary function from `Double` to `Double`:

```
def scale(f: Double => Double) = f(d)
```

Now, maybe you have an idea of a *default* scale.  That's probably no scaling at all.  So you might want a function that takes a `Double` and returns the very same `Double`.

```
val unscaled = (d: Double) => d
```

We store the function in a `val` because we don't want to keep creating it over and over again.  Now we can use this function as a default argument:

```
class Scalable(d: Double) {
  val unscaled = (d: Double) => d
  def scale(f: Double => Double = unscaled) = f(d)
}
```

Now we can call both `x.scale` and `x.scale(_*2)` and `x.scale(math.sqrt)` and they'll all work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are differences in bytecode. And yes, there are guidelines.

1. With `=`: This declares a method which accepts a parameter and returns the last expression in the right hand side block, which has the type `Unit` here.
2. Without `=`: This declares a method which does not have a return value, that is, the return type is always `Unit`, irrespective of what the type of the last expression in the right hand side block is.
3. With `=>`: This declares a method which returns a *function object* of type `scala.xml.Node => Unit`. Every time you invoke this method `func3`, you will construct a new function object on the heap. If you write `func3(node)`, you will first invoke `func3` which returns the function object and then invoke the `apply(node)` on that function object. This is slower than just calling a plain method directly as in cases 1. and 2.
4. As a `var`: This declares a variable and creates a function object as in 3., but the function object is created only **once**. Using this to call the function object is in most cases slower than just a plain method call (may not be inlined by JIT), but at least you do not recreate the object. If you want to avoid the danger of someone reassigning the variable `func4`, use a `val` or a `lazy val` instead.
5. This is syntactic sugar for 1. when blocks contain only a single expression.

Note that if you use the forms 1., 2. and 5. with the higher-order `foreach` method, Scala will still create a function object which calls `func1`, `func2` or `func5` implicitly, and pass that to `foreach` (it will not use a method handle or smth like that, at least not in current versions).
In these cases, the generated code will roughly correspond to:

```
xmlNodes.iterator.foreach((node: scala.xml.Node) => funcX(node))
```

So, the guideline is - unless you are using the same function object every time, just create an ordinary method as in 1., 2. or 5. It will be lifted to a function object anyway, where this is needed.
If you realize that this generates a lot of objects because calling such method happens often, you might want to micro-optimize by using the form 4. instead to ensure that the function object for `foreach` gets created only once.

Where deciding between 1., 2. and 5. is concerned, one guideline is - if you have a single statement, use form 5.

Otherwise, if the return type is `Unit`, then use the `def foo(): Unit = {` form if this is public API, so that clients looking at your code quickly and clearly see the return type.
Use the `def foo() {` form for methods with return type `Unit` which are private, for your own convenience of shorter code. But this is just one particular guideline regarding style.

For more, see: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#methods

Answer (score 2):

Well, 1, 2, and 5 aren't functions *at all*, they are *methods*, which are fundamentally different from functions: methods *belong to* objects and are not themselves objects, whereas functions *are* objects.

1, 2, and 5 are also exactly the same: if you have only one statement, then you don't need curly braces to group several statements, ergo 5 is the same as 1. Leaving off the `=` sign is syntactic sugar for declaring a return type of `Unit`, but `Unit` is also the inferred return type for 1 and 5, so 2 is the same as 1 and 5.

3 is a method which, when called, returns a function. 4 is a variable which points to a function.

Comment: I though in Scala everything is an object :) isn't it so?

Comment: @EranMedan: That depends on your definition of "object" and every-"thing". "Object" can mean "entity that can be manipulated by the program" (which I will call *object* from now on), or "value that is a member of the object system" (which I will call `Object` from now on). In Scala, everything that can be manipulated by the program (i.e. every *object*) is also an `Object`, i.e. an instance of a class (unlike Java, where primitives can be manipulated by the program (i.e. are *objects* in that sense of the word), but aren't `Object`s). In Scala, this distinction doesn't exist: every *object*

Comment: is also an `Object` and every `Object` is also an *object*. However, there are things in the language, which cannot be manipulated by the program and which aren't instances of a class, i.e. they are neither *object* s nor `Object`s. These are, for example, methods, types, classes, traits, variables, syntax, parameter lists. For example, if classes were `Object`s, then they could have methods and fields, just like any other object, and we wouldn't need companion objects. Note: you can use Scala's reflection API, to give you an object that *represents* a class, or a trait, or a type. But that

Comment: object is only a proxy, it is *not* the real thing. So, when we say "everything is an object", what we really mean is that "every *object* is an `Object`", i.e. that everything which can be manipulated by the program is also a member of the object system, or in other words, there are no values *outside of* the object system (unlike primitives in Java). We do *not* mean that everything that exists in the language can also be manipulated at runtime by the program. Note that with methods this distinction is somewhat obscured by the fact that Scala will automatically convert methods to functions

Comment: in certain cases. That's why 1, 2, and 5 work in your example: the compiler sees that `foreach` expects a function but you are passing it a method, but the signature of the method matches that of the expected function, so, it will create a function for you.

Answer (score 1):

1-2. When you throw away equals sign, your function becomes procedure (returns Unit, or just nothing).
3. In third case you defined a function `scala.xml.Node => Unit`, that returns a function.
4. Same, but you've assigned some function `scala.xml.Node => Unit` to variable. The difference explained in [Differences between these three ways of defining a function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646756/scala-def-versus-val)
5. No difference, comparing with 1. But you can't write multiline statements like that.