# cache using functional callbacks/ proxy pattern implementation scala

Tags: scala, caching, functional-programming, proxy-pattern

## How to implement cache using functional programming

A few days ago I came across callbacks and proxy pattern implementation using scala.
This code should only apply inner function if the value is not in the map.
But every time map is reinitialized and values are gone (which seems obivous.

**How to use same cache again and again between different function calls**

```
class Aggregator{
  def memoize(function: Function[Int, Int] ):Function[Int,Int] = {
    val cache = HashMap[Int, Int]()
     (t:Int) => {
      if (!cache.contains(t)) {
        println("Evaluating..."+t)
        val r = function.apply(t);
        cache.put(t,r)
        r
      }
       else
      {
        cache.get(t).get;
      }
    }
  }

  def memoizedDoubler = memoize( (key:Int) => {
    println("Evaluating...")
    key*2
    })
  }

object Aggregator {

  def main( args: Array[String] ) {
    val agg = new Aggregator()
    agg.memoizedDoubler(2)
    agg.memoizedDoubler(2)// It should not evaluate again but does
    agg.memoizedDoubler(3)
    agg.memoizedDoubler(3)// It should not evaluate again but does

 }
```

Comment: Put `cache` outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do here, the reason it's not working is that every time you call `memoizedDoubler` it's first calling `memorize`. You need to declare `memoizedDoubler` as a `val` instead of `def` if you want it to only call `memoize` once.

```
  val memoizedDoubler = memoize( (key:Int) => {
    println("Evaluating...")
    key*2
  })
```

This answer has a good explanation on the difference between `def` and `val`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12856386/37309

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you declaring a new `Map` per invocation ?

```
def memoize(function: Function[Int, Int] ):Function[Int,Int] = {
    val cache = HashMap[Int, Int]()
```

rather than specifying *one per instance* of `Aggregator` ?

e.g.

```
class Aggregator{
  private val cache = HashMap[Int, Int]()
  def memoize(function: Function[Int, Int] ):Function[Int,Int] = {
```

Comment: A field which is a mutable collection inside a method. **is that a good idea for distributed program like spark**

Comment: Bit confused. You can't declare a field within a method

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> How to implement cache using functional programming

In functional programming there is no concept of mutable state. If you want to change something (like cache), you need to return updated cache instance along with the result and use it for the next call.

Here is modification of your code that follows that approach. `function` to calculate values and `cache` is incorporated into `Aggregator`. When `memoize` is called, it returns tuple, that contains calculation result (possibly taken from cache) and new `Aggregator` that should be used for the next call.

```
class Aggregator(function: Function[Int, Int], cache:Map[Int, Int] = Map.empty) {

  def memoize:Int => (Int, Aggregator) = {
    t:Int =>
      cache.get(t).map {
        res =>
          (res, Aggregator.this)
      }.getOrElse {
        val res = function(t)
        (res, new Aggregator(function, cache + (t -> res)))
      }
  }
}

object Aggregator {

  def memoizedDoubler = new Aggregator((key:Int) => {
    println("Evaluating..." + key)
    key*2
  })


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val (res, doubler1)  = memoizedDoubler.memoize(2)
    val (res1, doubler2)  = doubler1.memoize(2)
    val (res2, doubler3)  = doubler2.memoize(3)
    val (res3, doubler4)  = doubler3.memoize(3)
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
Evaluating...2
Evaluating...3
```